# Compile a dynamic directive with a fragment of the parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to insert a dynamic directive and pass it through a mini-scope taken from the parents larger model, i.e. `$scope.model[i]` where `i` is the index of the list item you just clicked.

What I kinda want to do is:

```
element.append($compile("<newdirective />")($scope.model[i]));
```

I could pass it the entire model and the index through the attributes but seems far than ideal.

Comment: I had trouble understanding that. What would the directive be getting out of the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found a way to do this by creating a new scope manually:

```
var newScope = $scope.$new();
newScope.model = $scope.model[i];
element.append($compile("<newdirective />")(newScope));
```

The only other way I could solve this would be to create a mini scope in the parent $scope let the child view use natural inheritance.

```
$scope.childScope = $scope.model[i];

//inside newdirective
<div ng-repeat="items in childScope"></div>
```